# llamar a un módulo como función para aplicarlo sobre una caja de texto

Tags: vb.net, modulos

Tengo este código que pretende llamar al módulo EnLetras.vb para hacer la conversión de número a letras pero tira el siguiente error:

> 'EnLetras' es un tipo y no se puede usar como expresión. (BC30108)

```
Sub Button1Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Label1.Text = ""
    If IsNumeric(TextBox1.Text) Then
        Label1.Text = (EnLetras(TextBox1.Text))
    End If
    Me.TextBox1.Select      
End Sub
```

Comment: No podes llamar a un modulo... En tal caso, llamaras a una funcion dentro del modulo...

Comment: ¿Y como se hace eso?

Answer (score 1):

No se puede llamar directamente a un módulo para usar una función que hay en él.
Lo que sí se puede hacer es llamar a una función que esté dentro de dicho módulo.
**Sintaxis:**

```
nombredelmódulo.nombredelafunción(parámetros)
```

En el ejemplo que puse quedaría así:

```
Sub Button1Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Label1.Text = ""
    If IsNumeric(TextBox1.Text) Then
        Label1.Text = EnLetras.EnLetras(TextBox1.Text) 'Llamo primero al módulo EnLetras y después a la función que también se llama EnLetras
    End If
    Me.TextBox1.Select      
End Sub
```